# Google oauth multiple domains

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, google-oauth

Is it possible to use the Google OAuth with multiple domains? I'm building a staff portal that would be helpful to allow users of our "branch" location sign in as well. However, I've only seen `hd=domain.com` and I have no idea if `hd=domain.com,domain1.com,domain2.com` would even be feasible or allowable.

Input?

Comment: Not sure if google would allow this, but you could create some middleware API on the authorised domain, then your other apps would go through that API, but it means implementing your own OAuth on your API for it to be safe.